# Working with PowerShell and file based DB operations

Tags: powershell

I have a scenario where I have a lot of files in a CSV file i need to do operations on. The script needs to be able to handle if script is stopped or failed, then it should continue where i stopped from. In a database scenario this would be fairly simple. I would have an updated column and update that when operation for the line has completed. I have looked if I somehow could update the CSV on the fly, but I dont think that is possible. I could start having multiple files, but not that elegant. Can anyone recommend some kind of simple file based DB like framework? Where I from PowerShell could create a new database file (maybe json) and read from it and update on the fly.

Comment: There's [Export-Clixml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-clixml?view=powershell-6) for object serialization. Would saving file names and statuses as a hashtable and persisting the state via serialization work for you?

Comment: Importing and exporting csv in powershell is pretty easy. You could keep all the data in memory and export it back to the csv file whenever something has changed (or maybe only when the script is stopped or fails, in a `finally` block maybe).

Comment: Thanks both. @marsze the problem is i have hundreds og thousands of data. So the loop can take a very long time. Your right, if you just at the end of the script exported to a new csv that would be easy. But the script must be able to handle if a user stops the script in the middle of the loop. Having a database can handle this kind of scenarioes. I think I will go for the SQLite seems its pretty proven.

Comment: @ThomasSegato I was about to suggest that. Everything else would just seem like you were trying to build a file-based little database on your own. Or wouldn't it suffice to store the current line number somewhere?

Comment: @marsze funny you mention it, that was actually the solution I ended up with through environments variable. Thanks for your help. Can you post an answer with the SQLite part then I close the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is really so complex, that you actually need somewhat of a local database solution, then consider to go with SQLite which was built for such scenarios.

In your case, since you process an CSV row-by-row, I assume storing the info for the current row only will be enough. (Line number, status etc.)